# Laravel Blade PHP - How to use @if statements to display different links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm making a site using laravel and i'm trying to display different links in the navigation bar if the users logged in.

Here's my code so far:

```
@if (Auth::check())
<li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
@else
<li><a href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="/auth/register">Register</a></li>
```

Do i need to

```
use Auth;
```

or something in the php file.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something? Got any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken directly from one of Laravel's older defaut views that used `bootstrap`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if (Auth::guest())
        <li><a href="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">Register</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/auth/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

You'll want to use `@if (Auth::guest())`

Also, be sure to include `@endif` which is required for `blade's @if`.